# is it possible to do `do; condition; while;` on bash?

Tags: bash

Is it possible to do `do; condition; while` loop in `bash`?

For example:

```
do
curl -f google.com/demo
while [ $? -ne 0 ]
done
```

If I do

```
while [ $? -ne 0 ]
do curl -f google.com/demo
done
```

...I depend on the command before the loop.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible.

The only valid alternative is to use break in an endless loop:

```
while :; do
   if ! curl -f google.com/demo
   then
       break
   fi
done
```

And anyway this looks like XY question and what you really want maybe is to loop until the command returns nonzero:

```
while ! curl -f google.com/demo; do :; done
```

or

```
until curl -f google.com/demo; do :; done
```

Comment: I assume he wants to repeat the command until the return value is 0: `until curl -f google.com/demo; do :; done`

Comment: @Cyrus Och, right, didn't think about it too long.

Comment: I edited out [the `$?` antipattern](/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)